# Does an array have a limit to how many lines can be read?

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
parserlines = [line.strip().split(",") for line in open("C:\\Python34\\filename_convention.txt", 'r')]
print(parserlines[1])

#[1]source_dir[2]source_pattern[3]target_dir[4]prefix

parserarrayI101 = parserlines[1]
parserarrayO101 = parserlines[2]
parserarrayI103 = parserlines[3]
parserarrayO103 = parserlines[4]
parserarrayI195 = parserlines[5]
parserarrayO195 = parserlines[6]
parserarrayI199 = parserlines[7]
parserarrayO199 = parserlines[8]
parserarrayI900 = parserlines[9]
parserarrayO900 = parserlines[10]
parserarrayI910 = parserlines[11]
parserarrayO910 = parserlines[12]
parserarrayI195 = parserlines[13]
parserarrayO195 = parserlines[14]
parserarrayI199 = parserlines[15]
parserarrayO199 = parserlines[16]

print(parserarrayI900[2])
```

Then I get the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
   File "C:\Python34\listtest.py", line 16, in <module>  
      parserarrayI910 = parserlines[11]  
IndexError: list index out of range
```

There are 16 lines in the file that need to be read. Also is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you know that in Python lists start with zero? Or you're skipping the first element on purpose with `parserlines[1]`? Are you sure `line.strip().split(',')` gives the result you want?

Comment: Yes the first line is a header. And i need the individual elements within the array.

Comment: could you please post a tiny bit of the input file (2-5 lines)?

Comment: there are no 16 lines. check the line endings

Comment: Despite being on MSDOS (or Windows), you do *not* have to use backslashes.  You can use `open("C:/Python34/filename_convention.txt", 'r')`.  This makes it easier to write, less likely to be a mistake, easier to read, and is supported on every Microsoft environment since DOS 2.0.

Comment: @wallyk, moreover, one can simply remove the `'r'` argument of `open` so it's even easier to write and understand.

Comment: I dunno, I'm favor of explicit declarations of the file mode, especially because different open protocols can have different default modes (such as tempfile, etc).

However, using "with open" here is.... a must.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no limit to the size of Python [lists](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists), which is what you are using (except for your system's memory). I believe they are implemented as flexible arrays; which means they are arrays under the hood, but they are dynamically resized to accommodate however many items you add to them.

The issue is with your file and how it's being read in. It could be line endings being misinterpreted, as suggested in the comments. Try printing out your `parserlines` variable immediately after reading the file, and it will show you how the file was actually read in. Consider using the [pretty print](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module to make it easier to see: `pprint.pprint(parserlines)`.

Answer (score 0):

If the data file was generated by a program observing MSDOS file conventions, then the line delimiter is "\r\n" instead of "\n".

That convention can be used by slightly modifying the open:

```
open("C:/Python34/filename_convention.txt", "rt")
```

The addition of `t` means use MSDOS text mode conventions.